# Set theory, show a set is countable, homework. check my answer

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-verification, infinity

I solved this question but there is something strange going on and I am unsure of myself. Would like someone to review it.

We are given a total order (or linear order) $<^{*}$on group $A$ such that for all $a \in A$:

$|\{x\in A | x<^{*}a\}|<\aleph_0$

We are asked to show that $A\leq \aleph_0$

**My solution**

if $<^{*}$ is a total order then there is an $a' \in A$ such that for all $x\in A$: $x<^{*}a'$.

so if we take $a=a': \{x\in A | x<^{*}a\}=A$  so we can infer that $A < \aleph_0$...

Here's what bothers me. We were asked to prove that $A \leq \aleph_0$ not $A < \aleph_0$. I know that what i proved shows both, but they aren't usually that lenient. if they wrote $\leq$ then that means there is a possiblity that $|A| = \aleph_0$, and according to my proof there isnt.

Have I done something wrong? I think that $A$ is a finite group. Else, $|\{x\in A | x<^{*}a\}|<\aleph_0$ won't be true for all $a$.

Comment: What if $A=\mathbb Z$, the group of integers, and we define $x\lt^*y\Leftrightarrow|x-\frac13|\lt|y-\frac13|$? That's a total order, isn't it?

Comment: I was wrong to assume that just because the relation is a total order, then $A$ has a maximal element. That was false.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue here is this: Why does $A$ have a maximal element? It doesn't have to.

**HINT:** Show that if $|\{x\in A\mid x<a\}|=|\{x\in A\mid x<a'\}|$ then $a=a'$. Conclude that there is an obvious injection from $A$ into $\Bbb N$.

Comment: $f: A->\mathbb N$, $f(a) = |\{x\in A | x<^{*}a\}|$ is injective.

Comment: That is correct Oria. One can also show that in the case of $A$ satisfying this property, either $A$ is finite or it is order isomorphic to $\Bbb N$ with the natural order.

Comment: Asaf could you give me an advice with one more thing. we are required to find such a total order $<^{*}$ on $A$ with the property that for all $a \in A$,  $|\{x \in A| x<^{*} a\}| < \aleph_0$ where $A = \mathbb Q \cap (0,1)$. I can't seem think of such a relation, every relation i think of does not necesarily maintain "$|\{x \in A| x<^{*} a\}| < \aleph_0$" for example the regular $\leq$ relation...

Comment: @Oria: Write each $x\in A$ as a reduced fraction $p/q$, and now decree that $p/q<^*n/m$ if and only if $2^p3^q<2^n3^m$, or something like that.